# How to conifgure specify sticky slot settings for Azure function using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment-slots

I have app settings that need to be sticky to deployment slots for Azure Function.

I followed example provided from below posting.

[How to use sticky staging slots in Azure Arm Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360370/how-to-use-sticky-staging-slots-in-azure-arm-templates)

However, when the resources are deployed onto resource through VSTS, it keeps failing due to 'conflict' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors).

I currently have separate resource templates for "Microsoft.Web/Sites" and "Microsoft.Web/Sites/Config"

App settings are specified under "siteConfig" properties for "Microsoft.Web/Sites" template.

If "appSettingNames" is a type of config, can I list it under siteConfig for "Microsoft.Web/Sites" like below?

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": "[parameters('appSettings')]",
                "alwaysOn": true,
                "appSettingNames": "[parameters('appSettingNames')]"
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [],
        "resources": []
    }
```

Where as parameter 'appSettingNames' is an array parameter and look like below:
["setting1", "setting2", "setting3"].

if there is any example for specifying this configuration.
it would be really helpful

Thanks

Comment: I think that looks right. Did you try it?

Comment: @davidEbbo I tried it, but it fails :(

Comment: Can you update your question with more details about exactly how it fails?

Comment: Also, please don't mix syntactic ARM template questions with Resource Provider specific questions. e.g. here, to simplify, show what you are trying in the simplest possible way, by directly hard coding the value that you want to set this to, as opposed to relying on [parameters] which is completely orthogonal to the Resource Provider concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, 'appSettingNames' is not a type of config. So you can not set the template you post. And you can see all the types of config follow this link: [SiteConfig object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites#siteconfig-object).

Comment: If it's not a type of config, how is the example from the link working?

Comment: What is the content of  "appSettings"?

Comment: `appSettingNames` is REAL and appears to be undocumented. For more info see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51873013/1777780