# How to use sticky staging slots in Azure Arm Templates (2019)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Using ARM templates I am trying to set "slotSetting: true" in my app service config - this seems to have been a options (see link below) in previous versions of the ARM template but I am not able to find how to do it with the latest version.

Link to how this was solved previously: [How to use sticky staging slots in Azure Arm Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360370/how-to-use-sticky-staging-slots-in-azure-arm-templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using a nested template with the older API to lock the settings but please add the correct solution if you have it!

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "appServiceName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "appSettingsToLock": {
        "type": "array"
    },
    "conncetionStringsToLock": {
        "type": "array"
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('appServiceName'),'/slotconfignames')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
        "properties": {
            "connectionStringNames": "[parameters('conncetionStringsToLock')]",
            "appSettingNames": "[parameters('appSettingsToLock')]"
        }
    }
]
}
```